# How to fix 404 error using thymleaf and spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

hi friends i creating simple spring boot web application and i getting 404 error but according to spring boot my code is correct
can you see my code

this is my pom.xml file

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>login</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>login</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
         <version>9.0.64</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
    

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
`
```

and i saw some videos and added **jasper dependency and swagger dependency **
even though my error not resolved

this is my controller

```
 `package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class AppController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    
    public String viem(){
        
        return "login";
        
    }

}
`
```

this is my html file

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
hi friends!!!
</body>
</html>`

    this is my main class 
  `package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoginApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginApplication.class, args);
    }

}
`
```

in console didn't came any exception

```
    `
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\
```

/  ***)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|*__/=/*/*/_/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

```
2022-07-21 15:29:18.856  INFO 4592 --- [           main] com.example.demo.LoginApplication        : Starting LoginApplication using Java 17.0.2 on DESKTOP-QQ1B52I with PID 4592 (C:\Users\dell\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.14.1.RELEASE\login\target\classes started by dell in C:\Users\dell\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.14.1.RELEASE\login)
2022-07-21 15:29:18.862  INFO 4592 --- [           main] com.example.demo.LoginApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-21 15:29:19.877  INFO 4592 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2022-07-21 15:29:19.889  INFO 4592 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-21 15:29:19.889  INFO 4592 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-07-21 15:29:20.144  INFO 4592 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2022-07-21 15:29:20.153  INFO 4592 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-21 15:29:20.153  INFO 4592 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1229 ms
2022-07-21 15:29:20.584  INFO 4592 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''
2022-07-21 15:29:20.596  INFO 4592 --- [           main] com.example.demo.LoginApplication        : Started LoginApplication in 2.146 seconds (JVM running for 3.001)
2022-07-21 15:29:33.986  INFO 4592 --- [nio-8082-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-21 15:29:33.987  INFO 4592 --- [nio-8082-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-07-21 15:29:33.990  INFO 4592 --- [nio-8082-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
`
```

but browser  i getting this error

`Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Thu Jul 21 15:29:36 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).`
```

Comment: try this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Nowhere does the `thymeleaf' dependency appear in pom.xml.

Comment: https://dev.to/reytech-lesson/spring-boot-hello-world-example-by-using-spring-initilizr-b7o

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).